# PHP weird scope error, empty variable

Tags: php, scope

Hello i have a weird scope problem

```
require 'connect.php';

$name = $_GET['R'];
echo $name;
if(isset($_POST['prev_password']) && isset($_POST['new_password']) && isset($_POST['rep_password'])) {
    echo $name;
    if(!empty($_POST['prev_password']) && !empty($_POST['new_password']) && !empty($_POST['rep_password'])) {
        $user_password = $_POST['prev_password'];
        $user_new_password = $_POST['new_password'];
        $user_rep_password = $_POST['rep_password'];

        if($user_new_password == $user_rep_password) {
            $mysql_query = sprintf("SELECT username, password FROM users WHERE username='$name'", $name);
            $query_run = mysql_query($mysql_query, $mysql_link) or die('COULD NOT PERFORM QUERY');

            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query_run)) {
                $qUser_name = $row['username'];
                $qUser_pass = $row['password'];                
            }

            if($qUser_name == $name) {
                echo 'Match';
                if($qUser_pass == $user_password) {
                    $mysql_query = sprintf("UPDATE users SET password='$user_new_password' WHERE username='$name'", $name);
                    $query_run = mysql_query($mysql_query, $mysql_link) or die('COULD NOT PERFORM QUERY');
                    echo header('Location: main.php?C=1');                    
                }else {
                    header('Location: main.php?C=4');
                }
            }
        }else {
            header('Location: main.php?C=3');
        }
    }else {
        header('Location: main.php?C=2');
    }
}
```

anyway, the problem is with the first variable $name, when i 'echo' $name its ok, displays the content correctly, but inside the (if sss) ITS EMPTY, idk why, i've tried using global, the GLOBALS array, and its still empty, ... so .. the query its executed with an empty parameter.

please help, if someone can see what could be possible wrong.

PD: this is a Changepassword.php the $_GET['R'] is getting from the user Main.php site, AND I KNOW, im not Hashing password,, that is not really the problem here

Comment: Are you absolutely certain you're even getting into that if (isset... statement?

Comment: Are you sure `$name` is empty and not `$qUser_name` for example ? on which line ? Also, do not use `mysql_*` it's deprecated and risky.

Comment: Show the output with  `echo $user; print_r($_GET); print_r($_POST);` before the first if

Comment: Can you confirm it is actually getting inside the if statement?

Comment: ya i tried echoing from inside the isset and it works

Comment: In fact, i can even see the 'Match' echo

Comment: im testing all of this in XAMPP btw, localhost

Comment: @GabrielMatusevich - so your code is getting as far as `Match`? Which means that it's passing the `if($qUser_name == $name) {` test? Can you var_dump both $name and $qUser_name, just before that if, please? (And the same for $qUser_pass and $user_password, too)

Comment: the if is checking true because the QUERY is returned empty, so $qUser is empty AS well as $name :P that's why is getting past that

Comment: i did the var_dump, both have NULL